# iptables not working with hotspot

Tags: iptables, wifi-hotspot

I created the rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 64.182.208.181 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Then, when I acess the site 64.182.208.181, instead of execute the normal page of this site, it will execute a script in my computer and return it.
It's work. But, if I to create a hotspot in my computer and going to this site using my cellphone, this will not work. Execute a normal page of this site.

Why? How to fix it, to working in my cellphone.

Comment: use PREROUTING instead OUTPUT

Comment: @Babyy I tried using `PREROUTING`, but, not working. The cellphone can't load the page. Well... I think that I need use `-t filter` instead of `-t nat`, rigth? http://i.imgur.com/ufLpSqz.png

Comment: @Babyy But table filter can't use `DNAT`. I receive the error message "x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: only valid in nat table, not filter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 64.182.208.181 -j DNAT --to 10.42.0.1
```

I need use `10.42.0.1` instead of `127.0.0.1`, becuse, for my cellphone, the hotspot's script is located in `10.42.0.1`, not in localhost.